# get computed field source field in CSOM/JSOM

Tags: 2010, javascript, csom, column, jsom

I know how to get all the fields in a list using CSOM/JSOM. What I cannot figure out is how to get the source field for computed fields.

For example, the LinkTitle field is a computed field soured from the Title field. So if I have the LinkTitle field, how would I get the name of the source field.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function()
{
    var listData = {};
    listData.clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    listData.list = listData.clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("test");
    listData.listFields = listData.list.get_fields();

    listData.clientContext.load(listData.list);
    listData.clientContext.load(listData.list, "EffectiveBasePermissions");
    listData.clientContext.load(listData.listFields);

    listData.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(listData, listDetailsLoaded), Function.createDelegate(listData, function(sender, args){if(this.onError) this.onError(1, args.get_message());}));
}, "sp.js");

function listDetailsLoaded(sender, args)
{
    var listData = this;
    var fieldEnumerator = listData.listFields.getEnumerator();
    while(fieldEnumerator.moveNext())
    {
        var thisField = fieldEnumerator.get_current();

        if(thisField.get_fieldTypeKind() == 12)
        {
            alert('computed field: ' + thisField.get_internalName());
            // get source field here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could retrieve the SchemaXml and parse the XML to find the FieldRefs

Comment: That is what I am doing right now but I felt as though there HAS to be a less-hacky way...

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan FWIW, SP Designer 2013 parses the SchemaXML to find the possible choice values for a site column. Here's the [query it generates](https://pastebin.com/ywxrFcCa). So, sometimes, that *is* the least hacky way. I suppose it's a catch-all for CSOM, in case a given feature isn't available.